# Im trying to auto populate in javascript some calculated user input... can you tell me why this keeps getting a parsing error?

Tags: javascript, html

trying to get the calculation results of user input and auto-populate them into the text input fields.. and it keeps giving me a parsing error...

```
enter code here

 function add_number(){
      var monthlyPayment = parseInt(document.getElementById("monthlyPayment").value);
      var maintFees = parseInt(document.getElementById("maintFees").value);
      var memFees = parseInt(document.getElementById("memFees").value);
      ar exchFees = parseInt(document.getElementById("exchFees").value);
      var result = (monthlyPayment?monthlyPayment:0) + (maintFees?maintFees:0) + (memFees?memFees:0) + 
    (exchFees?exchFees:0);
  document.getElementById("txtresult").value = result;}

function mpTwelve(){
  var monPay = parseInt(document.getElementById("monthlyPayment").value);
  var monTwe = monPay * 12;

  document.getElementById("mpTimesTwelve").value = monTwe;}

function maintTwelve(){
  var maintPay = parseInt(document.getElementById("maintFees").value);
  var maintTwe = maintPay * 12;

  document.getElementById("maintTimesTwelve").value = maintTwe;}

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('input')).forEach((i)=>{
    i.addEventListener('change', (event) => {add_number();mpTwelve();maintTwelve();})})
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: ERROR: Parsing error: Assigning to rvalue